# jQuery pagination... does this mean the entire page is not loaded at once?

Tags: jquery, pagination

I have a large amount of data being displayed in a page using wordpress, so I thought I would search for some sort of jQuery pagination system to split the data up in order to load only the data on the viewable page, not the ENTIRE page of over 1000 posts (which crashes my browser :/)

But... I just wondered if this would actually make a difference? I have found a tutorial on what I want which is here http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-jquery-pagination-system/.

Would this do what I want? Or simply allow a more convenient way to split the data up without solving my page load issue?

Answer (score 3):

That example won't fix your problem as it still relies on all the data (in your case the 1000 posts) being loaded into the page first and it then hides/shows a subset of them.

What you will need to create is a method of retrieving a subset of your data from the server - for example 20 per page - and displaying them. Then when the user requests the next page you would need to make a new request via AJAX to get the next 20 posts from the database.

This way the browser is only ever given 20 posts at a time and won't causes you any problems. Exactly how you achieve that with Wordpress I'm not sure as I've never used it.

Alternatively you could make a completely new HTTP request for each page of posts. I'm sure Wordpress already has that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

> Or simply allow a more convenient way to split the data up without solving my page load issue?

Exactly. It would still query all of the items from the database and put them into your page and then simply hide them.

You need to implement a system of paging that only actually downloads the content that you want displayed for each 'page'.